# T-SQL calculate the percent increase or decrease between the earliest and latest for each project

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below, I am trying to run a query in T-SQL to get the earliest and latest costs for each project_id according to the date column and calculate the percent cost increase or decrease and return the data-set show in the second table (I have simplified the table in this question).

```
project_id  date        cost
-------------------------------
123          7/1/17     5000
123          8/1/17     6000
123          9/1/17     7000
123         10/1/17     8000
123         11/1/17     9000
456          7/1/17    10000
456          8/1/17     9000
456          9/1/17     8000
876          1/1/17     8000
876          6/1/17     5000
876          8/1/17    10000
876         11/1/17     8000
```

Result:

(Edit: Fixed the result)

```
project_id        "cost incr/decr pct"
------------------------------------------------
123                80% which is (9000-5000)/5000
456                -20%
876                 0%
```

Whatever query I run I get duplicates.

This is what I tried:

```
select distinct 
    p1.Proj_ID, p1.date, p2.[cost], p3.cost,
    (nullif(p2.cost, 0) / nullif(p1.cost, 0)) * 100 as 'OVER UNDER'
from
    [PROJECT] p1
inner join
    (select  
         [Proj_ID], [cost], min([date]) min_date
     from
         [PROJECT]
     group by 
         [Proj_ID], [cost]) p2 on p1.Proj_ID = p2.Proj_ID
inner join
    (select  
         [Proj_ID], [cost], max([date]) max_date
     from
         [PROJECT]
     group by 
         [Proj_ID], [cost]) p3 on p1.Proj_ID = p3.Proj_ID
where 
    p1.date in (p2.min_date, p3.max_date)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? you can get the `min` and `max` and calculate to your liking.

Comment: Why would you get the last row in your desired result?   Your sample data doesn't have a row for 876 with 7/1/17.

Comment: @TabAlleman: sorry i fixed the result. Fixed the 876 as well so it matches the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have a `first_value()` aggregation function.  It does have an analytic function, though.  So, you can do:

```
select distinct project_id,
       first_value(cost) over (partition by project_id order by date asc) as first_cost,
       first_value(cost) over (partition by project_id order by date desc) as last_cost,
       (first_value(cost) over (partition by project_id order by date desc) /
        first_value(cost) over (partition by project_id order by date asc)
       ) - 1 as ratio
from project;
```

If `cost` is an integer, you may need to convert to a representation with decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` and `OUTER APPLY` over `top 1` ... prior to SQL 2012

```
select 
min_.projectid,
latest_.cost - min_.cost [Calculation]
from
(select 
 row_number() over (partition by projectid order by date) rn
 ,projectid
 ,cost
 from projectable) min_   -- get the first dates per project
outer apply (
select 
 top 1 
   cost
 from projectable 
where 
projectid = min_.projectid    -- get the latest cost for each project
order by date desc
) latest_
where min_.rn = 1
```

Comment: I think in the `outer apply` clause after from `porjectable`, we should have `where` instead of `and`

Answer (score 0):

This might perform a little better

```
;with costs as (
    select      *,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY date) mincost,
                ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY date desc) maxcost
    from        table1
)
select      project_id,
            min(case when mincost = 1 then cost end) as cost1,
            max(case when maxcost = 1 then cost end) as cost2,
            (max(case when maxcost = 1 then cost end) - min(case when mincost = 1 then cost end)) * 100 / min(case when mincost = 1 then cost end)  as [OVER UNDER]
from        costs a 
group by    project_id
```